# What is the right preposition when you shoot?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

What is the right preposition when you shoot somebody with a gun or a camera?

> You should always shoot to/in/at/for/into the legs.

Comment: For photography, you usually say *take a shot of...* For self-defense purposes, you usually *aim for* the center of mass.

Answer (score 1):

"at" or "for" are both fine, although I would suggest that if you are talking firearms that center-of-mass is generally a much better target than legs. Pictures it would depend on what about the subject you are trying to emphasize.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'd use the same construction for a gun and a camera. For a gun, I agree with SoronelHaetir, either *at* or *for* seems fine. But for a camera, it feels awkward to me to say, “You should always shoot *X* the legs.” More likely I'd say, “You should always *aim* at the legs.”

I think the difference is this: In the case of guns, the transitive usage, “shoot the leg,” and the intransitive usage, “shoot at the leg,” mean roughly the same thing. The former is more definite, but they both imply pointing the gun at the leg and firing. When talking about photography, though, the intransitive meaning of *shoot* as “take photographs” is (to me) more general and directionless. It's an activity, like *paint*.

You can *aim* at the legs because that's a statement about where you the photographer are looking. However, I have nothing to back any of this up other than my intuition as a native speaker.

PS. Using *aim* works equally well for a gun.

Comment: You said that either _at_ or _for_ seems fine, but it seems that you prefer using _at_ and not _for_. :)

Comment: I didn't use "at/for" in every example, but I think either would be appropriate. There's only a small difference between them in my mind: "shoot at" and "aim at" are directional, whereas "shoot for" and "aim for" are more goal- or target-oriented.